# Windows Phone - custom control how propagate event to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am creating custom control for menu and I have ListBox in my control. Something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MenuItemsList"
         Grid.Row="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramList, Mode=OneWay}">
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Margin="10">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                  </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Now when I want to catch Tap event, get properties from class and keep MVVM model. How can I catch this in MainPage.xaml.cs or in MainViewModel?

I have this code in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<controls:BottomMenu x:Name="BottomMenu" Canvas.Top="{Binding MenuCanvasTop}"
                             Width="480" Height="400">
</controls:BottomMenu>
```

I have prepare this code in my MainViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand<string> GoToSectionCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return goToArticleCommand
                    ?? (goToArticleCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(
                         NavigateToSection));
            }
        }
```

But I don't know how can I call it. What's the best way?

**Edit:**
I tried to extend listbox:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="MenuItemsList"
                                     Grid.Row="1"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramList, Mode=OneWay}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                            <Button Content="{Binding Title}" 
                                                    Command="{Binding ListButtonClickCommand, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Url}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
```

With code-behind:

```
    public ICommand ListButtonClickCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ListButtonClickCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListButtonClickCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListButtonClickCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ListButtonClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BottomMenu), new PropertyMetadata(null)); 

    public BottomMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then in MainPage.xaml:

```
    <controls:BottomMenu x:Name="BottomMenu" Canvas.Top="{Binding MenuCanvasTop}"
                         Width="480" Height="400"
                         ListButtonClickCommand="{Binding MenuItemButtonCommand}">

    </controls:BottomMenu>
```

And in MainViewModel:

```
    private ICommand menuItemButtonCommand;
    public ICommand MenuItemButtonCommand
    {

        get
        {
            return menuItemButtonCommand
                ?? (menuItemButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(
                     NavigateToArticleSection));
        }

    }
```

For now without luck. It's not working. RelayCommand isn't triggered.

**Edit2**
I guess the problem is with binding command in custom control but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to bind to the UserControl -- using "RelativeSource Self" will bind to the Button, which is not what you want.   You should be able to use an "ElementName" binding to locate the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="UserControlName" ... >

    ...

        <Button Content="{Binding Title}" 
                Command="{Binding ElementName=UserControlName,Path=ListButtonClickCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Url}"/>

    ...

</UserControl>
```